# Are there any implementations of the import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient interface in Java?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Are there any implementations of the `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` interface I can use in Java?

I can't seem to find any that I can use because I do not want to implement all of the `HttpClient` interface methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder` to configure and create your HttpClientInstance.

Example:

```
 // create a builder
 HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

 // optionally configure it to your needs, e.g., 
 builder.disableAutomaticRetries();

 // finally get your HttpClient
 CloseableHttpClient client = builder.build();
```

See [this link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) for the complete JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

See org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient

It is annotated as @ThreadSafe while org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder is not.

What is more it implements Java 7 Closable interface.

Cheers.

Comment: `HttpClientBuilder` is just a Builder for `HttpClient`s. It does not have to be thread-safe itself. As the JavaDoc states, the `build()` method will return a `CloseableHttpClient` itself, which is again thread-safe and `Closeable`. See my updated answer. Also, according to the JavaDoc of all the `HttpClient` implementations, `HttpClientBuilder` is actually the way to go.